# Label QGIS diagram sector with percentage etc

Tags: qgis, labeling, diagram

I'm working with QGIS 2.14.3, using the diagrams function for vector layers. Is it possible to label each single diagram sector with an attribute / calculated percentage? In the layer properties tab / labels I only see an option to label the whole feature. In the diagrams menu, I can't find any labelling option.

It would be very nice to label for example every single pillar in this diagram with an attribute / calculated percentage. The displayed label is the label of the whole feature.

[image]

Comment: I was running this procedure but I could not link it with the path and hence end up using the same graphs in every coordinate. Could you please tell me what might have been wrong?

Answer (score 3):

In QGIS you can not add labels to diagrams.

1. the technique I use:
2. create the diagrams with the sheet google drive;
3. Save as image;
4. edit and save as svg with inkscape;
5. in the table of the shapefile attributes add a field: 'path' (Text 254);
6. populate the field with paths to images svg;
7. I extract the centroid of the shapefile and use the style 'symbol SVG';
8. Follow the screenshots:

table attribute
[image: image_1]

style 'symbol SVG'
[image: image_2]

assembly view of
[image: image_3]

other diagrams
[image: image_4]